# Routing network traffic on Android applications during runtime

Tags: android, network-programming

The application we are implementing allows the user's phone to be connected to a network via WiFi without having access to the internet (through that network), and using their phone's mobile data connection at the same time. The application will be hitting web services through the network it's connected to, while able to still hit other services outside it's network through the data plan. The behavior for this isn't as expected; it works on iOS but not available on Android, so I developed a way to manually route the network traffic leaving my application.

My current work around is limited to only Android version 6.0 (Api 23) and up. What I've done is manually assigning where the traffic should go via the ConnectivityManager's Network Request api:

```
NetworkRequest request = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
            .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
            //.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) //In case it should go through WiFi instead
            .build();
connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request, new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onAvailable(Network network) {
            connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
            //Handle API Request
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnavailable() {
            //Handle error logic
        }
    });
```

I've gotten this to work, albeit may not be practical, and I'm able to change which network I should send my requests through. However, with the app open and unfocused, other applications are able to access the internet through the phone's data plan. Once the app is closed, the behavior goes back to normal and the phone can hit services through the network, but not on the web (or vice versa, it's different depending on your Android phone).

What I would like to know if there is a way to revert back to the normal behavior when the app is unfocused (ie, during onPause() of my activity). Having the route set manually for other applications might not be ideal for the end user experience, nor might it pass through Google's terms.